# Modules appear to install, but don't show up

Tags: 7

I'm trying to install new modules via the url installer and uploader. I supply my sftp credentials. It says everything is fine. Then it says my module was installed successfully. However the new module doesn't show in the listing and it isn't in the sites/all/modules folder. What could I be missing?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In CentOS 7 my system is using systemd. By default systemd has `PrivateTmp=true` Because of this apache wasn't able to see the files that were uploaded via sftp so they couldn't copy them to the modules folder. I had to disable this. On my system that meant editing `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service` change 'PrivateTmp' to false. Save. Run `systemctl daemon-reload`. Then `systemctl restart httpd.service`.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem recently with a Centos server. If this is your scenario try

`# chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t ./sites/all/modules`

From `man chcon` change security context, recurse, verbose, type is web content.

Note. Probably a good idea to check what type the files that *are* working are first.

`$ sudo ls --lcontext google_analytics/
-r--r--r--. 1 unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 apache apache 31504 Jan 15 14:41 googleanalytics.admin.inc`

Comment: isn't this only an issue if running selinux? I'm not right now.